# Conditionally update field in datasheet view when row is modified?

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I have a requirement for an Access Database to add 3 new fields: [Entered By], [Entered On], and [Reviewed By].

Part of the requirement is that when the record is modified the [Reviewed By] field will blank out/null itself to signify that the record needs another review.

The way users modify these records is by clicking a button that runs a macro with the OpenQuery action with View set to Datasheet and Data Mode set to edit.

In this scenario am I able to catch a modification event and blank out the field?

Comment: We are best at helping once you've tried some things yourself and present them. Right now it sounds like you've been given a project and have just dumped it here.

Comment: @music2myear I'm sorry if it didn't come across this way but this is an "Is it possible?" question. I would never expect anyone to do my work for me, but I had no idea where to even begin or if this was possible to achieve. Just needed a simple point to the right direction on where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are able to "catch a modification event" and you can use this to blank out the field.

In actuality you want to add a [Before Change event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/before-change-macro-event) to the table. To do so:

1. Open the table in Datasheet View

[image: Open Table in Datasheet View]

2. On the "Table" tab click on the "Before Change" button

[image]

3. Add your actions as desired to accomplish your need. Use the `Updated("Field Name")` function to check if a field has changes applied. Note that any actions you define here will fire only once the user has moved off of the row either by hitting enter on the last cell or clicking onto another row.

[image]